# Web application response header duplication

Tags: java, apache, security, wildfly, wildfly-15

I am working on the security enhancements of my application based on a security scan report. My application is a java EE web application running in wildfly. And it is exposed to the users through a reverse proxy server which is Apache.

I did the following changes in the standalone.xml file in Wildfly to enable strict transport security and httponly attributes.

```
<server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
        <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-frame-options"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-xss-protection"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-content-type-options"/>
                <filter-ref name="transport-security"/>
             </host>
</server>
<servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config x-powered-by="false"/>
                <session-cookie http-only="true" secure="true"/>
                <websockets/>
</servlet-container>
```

However, when I go to the application page and check the response in the network tab, I see duplicate attributes.

```
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 4222
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2021 02:36:52 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Server: Apache
SET-COOKIE: JSESSIONID=BOH0IrY-e2q24ks1bbMy9bBzqeDZshm1n1O02G_f; Path=/MyApplication; HttpOnly
SET-COOKIE: JSESSIONID=BOH0IrY-e2q24ks1bbMy9bBzqeDZshm1n1O02G_f.application_uat; path=/MyApplication; secure; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Also, in one, JSESSIONID is secure and in the other one its not secure. I am not handling the configuration of Apache server. Could it be because of some configuration of the Apache server ? I am quite new to this so appreciate some help to figure this out.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it could due to some apache configuration based on the differnt value of the strict transport-securty, in this case the apache should not process the headers and just do a past through of the headers, if you talk with the apache server team, they can check the response, before and after it passes through the apache

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the application's source code, check to see if it has a custom cookie handler developed in-house.

Could be something as stupid as a piece of code that appends some text instead of overwriting it somewhere.

evidence suggests this:

```
SET-COOKIE: JSESSIONID=BOH0IrY-e2q24ks1bbMy9bBzqeDZshm1n1O02G_f; Path=/MyApplication; HttpOnly
SET-COOKIE: JSESSIONID=BOH0IrY-e2q24ks1bbMy9bBzqeDZshm1n1O02G_f.application_uat; path=/MyApplication; secure; HttpOnl
```

Effectively identical lines, with extra information added somewhere. suggests a handler that changes something along the way.

same goes for

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
```

which is kind of weird.

at any rate... it looks like something's dealing with 2 requests and modifying the same throughput... badly.